# get_user_pages_fast() for DMA?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a Linux driver that does DMA transfers to/from a device. For sending data to the device (to prevent copy operations) the driver maps the userspace buffer and uses it for DMA directly via `get_user_pages_fast()`. The user pages are then added to a scatter-gather list and used for DMA.

This works rather well, but the one issue is that this forces the userspace buffer to have various alignment requirements to the cache line of the CPU. My system returns `128` when you call `dma_get_cache_alignment()`, which means that in userspace I have to ensure that the start address is aligned to this value. Also, I have to check that the buffer is sized to a multiple of 128.

I see two options for handling this:

1. Deal with it. That is, in userspace ensure that the buffer is properly aligned. This sounds reasonable, but I have run into some issues since my device has to be integrated into a larger project, and I don't have control over the buffers that get passed to me. As a result, I have to allocate a properly aligned buffer in userspace to sit between the driver and the application and use that buffer in the event the caller's buffer is not aligned. This adds a copy operation and isn't the end of the world, but the resulting code is rather messy.
2. Rework the driver to use a kernel space buffer. That is, change the code such that the driver uses `copy_from_user()` to move the data into a properly aligned kernel space buffer. I'm not too concerned about the performance here, so this is an option, but would require a good amount of rework.

Is there anything that I'm missing? I'm hoping that there might be some magic flag or something that I overlooked to remove the alignment requirement altogether.

Comment: "1. Deal with it" was the approach we took. It was relatively easy because the device access used a special API anyway.
On Windows the dma buffer is allocated using VirtualAlloc, on Linux with valloc.